# MySQL settings for MAXIMUM performance / can be specific to particular DB or user?

Tags: mysql, memory-usage, performance-tuning, cpu-usage

We have a dedicated server, a very powerful one, and I don't believe we are getting the most out of MySQL. Even when running ultra-heavy processes that take a very long time to complete, I'm showing minimal CPU & memory usage, as if we have a gattling gun at our disposal, and we're using it to shoot BB's.

I would like to create a setup where MySQL is taking FULL ADVANTAGE of the powerful setup we have going. What kind of settings do I need to add to my.cnf in order to make this happen?

Additionally, I was wondering if there was any way we could control which user accounts would have access to higher performance-levels. Most of the accounts on our server are clients of ours. We have one account specifically that would like to have a giant share of the overall DB usage. Is this possible?

Comment: http://www.percona.com/

Comment: more specifically [Percona Online Tools](https://tools.percona.com/) and [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) if you want to go at it yourself.  Hire Percona or another MySQL consulting organization if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thank you both. We may end up going the consulting route. Was hoping this might be a simpler solution like http://serverfault.com/questions/321805/best-mysql-cache-settings-for-8gb-ram-dedicated-mysql-server-using-only-innodb. Perhaps I should just try these settings first and see where it takes us...

Comment: -1 because you didn't even say what storage engine your using.

Comment: It's a combination of MyISAM for most, and InnoDB for order & customer tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very hard thing, it depends on maany maaany other things including database structures. If you want to follow optimal settings and have some improvement with one our post, then only thing I can suggest is to use some tools like this:

https://raw.github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl

Hire good DBA/Sysadmin.

P.S. MySQL server performance cannot be adjusted for particular DB/user/table etc.